# Populate field in one layer with corresponding value from another layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, point, vector

I have 2 existing vector layers: 1 point, 1 polygon. In almost all cases the points overlap a polygon.

The point layer has multiple features (1,000+) with an existing field which I need to retrospectively populate with the equivalent value for the polygon feature which they overlap. How do I do this (without doing it manually)?

In future ideally I would like this to happen automatically when features are created/edited.

I have looked at various similar threads on here, but none of them quite answer the question. It appears that the Autofields plugin might be the solution, but that does not seem to be available anymore?

I am currently using QGIS 3.6.3

Comment: Please specify, whether you want to do this upon feature creation, or for already existing features. - Edit: Maybe provide an excerpt of the attribute tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use PyQGIS. You can do this with the Field Calculator.

1. Install the RefFunctions Plugin (this gives you access to new functions like `geomintersects`).
2. Use the Field Calculator to update the field in the point layer using this expression:

   ```
   geomintersects( 'polygons','ID')
   ```

   where `'polygons'` is the name of your polygon layer, and `'ID'` is the name of the field in the polygon layer that you want to copy into the point layer.

This will populate the field with the polygon values. To keep the field up-to-date, there are several options. Choose the one that best suits your needs:

- Every time you add new features, repeat the steps above to update the field. However, there's no need to do it one at a time. Make as many new features as you want, then select the new features and update the field using the Field Calculator and choosing the options "update existing field" and "selected features only".
- Use the Field Calculator to add a *virtual field*, using the same expression as above. The virtual field will be always updated whenever there's a change. When you create new features, they will always have the updated information. However, a virtual field is only stored in the project, so if you import the layer into a different project this field will be missing.
- Use a *default value* for the field. Open the layer properties > attribute form. Input the same expression in the "default value" text box.

  [image]

Comment: How does geomintersects handle cases where two polygons overlap?

Comment: It picks one of them. (I have no information about how it makes the choice.) If you have specific requirements for multiple overlapping polygons, you can make it conditional on `intersecting_geom_count('polygons') = 1`, and handle any other cases manually.

Comment: That works perfectly. I'm finding the 'apply default value on update' option is particularly useful when editing the layers

Comment: Is there an expression I can use to generate an 8 figure grid reference in the same way? I presume this is within the Geometry functions, but none of them seem appropriate.

Comment: @JimS-W Generate an 8-figure grid reference based on what? Does the grid reference already exist as an attribute in another layer? Or will it be randomly generated? Does it need to be unique? Will it be calculated somehow, and if so on what basis will it be calculated? This is probably complicated enough to be a separate question.

Comment: It would be an 8-figure grid reference for the location of the point feature(s). I'll add it as another question.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in the last few weeks: I am now getting 'Eval Error: error: targetLayer not present' every time I try to use the same expression with the same layer. Is there an issue with the plugin?

Comment: That's possible. Check the plugin manager and see if you need to update your version of the plugin. If that doesn't fix it, make a bug report.

Answer (score 4):

For your first part, you can use the tool `Join attributes by location`

[image]

Comment: Looks like that should work, with a bit of experimentation, thanks.

Is there any way to do this directly within the existing points layer, rather than creating a new layer?

Comment: You can by using PyQGIS but it's a little more complicated. You can validate my answer if it suits you.

Comment: Not familiar with PyQGIS - would this allow it to do it automatically for new features?

Comment: This is possible by using "signal" but it is still an additional degree of difficulty so don't start with that to discover the language.